# Check if model has a nested model connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a 3 models: `Collection`, `Product` and `Gallery`. Not every product has a gallery. How do I find those?

This is what I came with:

```
Collection.find_each do |collection|
  collection.products.each do |product|
    next if collection.products.empty?
    puts "Product #{product.id} does not have gallery" unless product.galleries.present?
  end
end
```

This is a bad way, because it sends a ton of queries. How can I improve that?

Upd.

```
class Collection    
  has_many :products
end

class Product    
  belongs_to :collection
  has_many :galleries
end

class Gallery    
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Comment: Not sure, but maybe something like this 
    `Collection.includes(products: [:galleries]).where(galleries: {id: nil})`

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the relationship between your models?

Comment: Probably something like this `Product.includes(:galleries).where(galleries: {id: nil})`

Comment: Updated post with model relations.

Comment: @alexxero the line of code in my previous comment will give you "all products that don't have any galleries"

Comment: @Mtihc, for some stupid reason I misread your comment. Both of them. And wasted more time on searching an answer. I'm sorry for being blind and thank you! That is exactly what I looked for. Won't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get "all products without galleries" in one single query, you can use this line of code

`Product.includes(:galleries).where(galleries: {id: nil})`